# Crop UIImageView's image in scale to fill mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, crop

I have one UIImageView which is in scale to fill mode. Now i want to crop the image in imageview. I have one rectangle on this imageview which user can move and change the size. After particular size is selected i want to crop the image using this frame. But since my mode of uiimageview is scale to fill this messes the cropping rectangle and different part is cropped. Has any one faced this problem. How to crop properly ?

Comment: Convert your cropping code to accommodate for the size difference..

Comment: You should read about coordinate spaces. It sounds like you want to display the image to the user in one space (the display space), but do the cropping in a different space (the image space).

Comment: look at this link may help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253270/how-to-crop-the-uiimage-in-iphone

Answer (score 0):

Your options are to calculate, or use this walkaround:

```
-(UIImage *)imageFromImageView:(UIImageView *)view withCropRect:(CGRect)cropRect
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * largeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([largeImage CGImage], cropRect);
UIImage* img = UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return img;
}
```

Comment: This causes the images to move to a different position. How would you keep the origin in the original spot?